# Invoke Perl script in Windows from OS X

Tags: macos, windows, perl

I have a Perl script written in Windows and an AppleScript written in OS X. I want the AppleScript to invoke the Perl script that is residing in Windows. How can I do this?

Comment: Is Windows on Boot Camp/Parallels/other computer?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have access to the file from your Mac system, for example through a shared folder, you would run it locally (through Terminal) like this:

```
perl /path/to/windows/shared/folder/scriptname.pl
```

In AppleScript this would be something like:

```
do shell script "/usr/bin/perl /path/to/windows/shared/folder/scriptname.pl
```

However, this still executes the Perl script from your local Mac instance. If you want to actually invoke it on the Windows server, that's a different ballgame. This would require you to setup remote access, through [for example SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004401/execute-remote-perl-script-on-a-windows-box-from-a-linux-box) or IIS on the Windows machine.